# Laravel schedule:run is not working when added into the cron job

Tags: php, laravel, cron

I have made a command and scheduled it for every 30 minutes. When I run `php artisan schedule:run` it works perfectly fine and returns with the expected results, but when I configured it on my live server my cron job do run but instead of retuning the success message it returns with list of all available command in my laravel project. Here is what I am doing.

**Command Kernel:**

```
$schedule->command('update:callLogs')
            ->everyMinute();
```

**Cron Entry:**

```
/usr/bin/php /home/ddsas9rm2f1g/public_html/clowdlink.com/crm/artisan schedule:run
```

And this is the response I am getting

> Laravel Framework 5.8.38

```
Usage:
command [options] [arguments]

Options:
 -h, --help            Display this help message
 -q, --quiet           Do not output any message
 -V, --version         Display this application version
  --ansi            Force ANSI output
  --no-ansi         Disable ANSI output
 -n, --no-interaction  Do not ask any interactive question
  --env[=ENV]       The environment the command should run under
 -v|vv|vvv, --verbose  Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug

Available commands:
 (List of all availabe commands)
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

**EDIT**
Now my command looks like this

```
* * * * * cd /home/ddsas9rm2f1g/public_html/clowdlink.com/crm && php artisan update:callLogs
```

but getting the same response whereas when I copy the same command and using putty ran the same command and it works perfectly fine. Now it's been a week now and I'm still stuck at this cron thing.

Comment: did you added this `* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: Yes I did tried it with this command but still results are same

Comment: Into my cPanel cron jobs

Comment: Now I changed my cron entry to `* * * * * /usr/bin/php cd /home/ddsas9rm2f1g/public_html/clowdlink.com/crm && php artisan schedule:run`

Comment: Getting this response when changed the command `Status: 404 Not Found
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.3.23
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

No input file specified.`

Comment: Yes, in the email I get when cron is run

Comment: When I run it in local it works perfectly fine and as you can see there is nothing wrong with my cron command then why it is not running.

Comment: your local setup and your live setup is different and different OS and PHP so check it

Comment: Sounds like you're running on a shared host. May I know where are you hosting? Also I think your PHP binary might be elsewhere. Perhaps do a `phpinfo()` and figure out the path, or echo `(new Symfony\Component\Process\PhpExecutableFinder)->find()` from your application to find out.

Comment: @sykez application is hosted on Godaddy and yes it's shared hosting.

Comment: @MohsinAbbas Were you able to find the PHP location? Try `/usr/local/bin/php /home/ddsas9rm2f1g/public_html/clowdlink.com/crm/artisan schedule:run`

Comment: Tried the same and it didn't help got the same results.

Comment: @MohsinAbbas How about that PHP location?

Comment: Anything on the location @MohsinAbbas?

Answer (score 5):

I fixed this by specifying the path to PHP instead of using just `php`.

From this: `cd /home/foobar && php artisan schedule:run`

To this: `cd /home/foobar && /usr/local/bin/php artisan schedule:run`

This stopped me from getting a list of available artisan commands and gave me the right output.

I can see it looks like you've already tried that, but I think others will run into this too. I'd imagine your issue is something to do with the PHP version you're using not being able to properly run PHP scripts. Maybe an opcache thing with CLI?

Answer (score 0):

I faced big challenge as well when I was deploying one my applications, and finally managed to tackle it with:

```
cd /path-to-project && /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/bin/php-cgi artisan schedule:run
```

I use Laravel 5.7 for my application

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have my project path got it from `__FILE__` magic function but what is this second path and how can I get that path can you please help me with that as well

Comment: Becasue the email I received now says `No such file or directory`

Comment: There are a few thing here, 1) You head to your project root folder by "cd  /path-to-project"   2) You specify which php version to be used to execute the artisan command

Comment: Is it possible to use Magic function in cron command line?

Comment: This is how my command look like now `* * * * * cd /home/ddsas9rm2f1g/public_html/clowdlink.com/crm && /usr/bin/php artisan schedule:run`

Comment: Still getting the same results **List of all availabel commands**

Comment: Is this the path for your application root directory?

Comment: Yes, This is my application root directory

Comment: Does your server (provider) let you execute php via cronjobs at all? Try to do something like

 `* * * * * cd /home/ddsas9rm2f1g/public_html/clowdlink.com/crm && /usr/bin/php testscript.php > testscriptoutput.txt
`

Add a echo "hello world" to that testscript and check your logs.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following code:

```
* * * * * php /home/ddsas9rm2f1g/public_html/clowdlink.com/crm/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

`>> /dev/null 2>&1`: we will discard all output of a command.

Comment: At this point OP should not be discarding all output! :-) Maybe once it is working, but not now ...

Comment: It's giving same output as Ihave mentioned in my question

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below in cron and share the output of crontab.out

```
* * * * * cd /home/ddsas9rm2f1g/public_html/clowdlink.com/crm/ && php artisan schedule:run >> crontab.out 2>&1
```

Comment: I have tried this command but getting the same output into the crontab.out file which I have added into my question.

Comment: @MohsinAbbas What happens if you run this command without cron? Can you substitute your local php installation in the command suggested above? Also, is the crontab running from the same user you are running the command from?

Comment: When I run this command without cron it works perfectly fine and returns the accurate results which are expected. I have already substituted my local php in the command and the results are same it returns list of all available artisan commands. Yes I am running the crontab with the same user I am running command from

Comment: No, I haven't done that. Could you please tell me more about this. How can I do that and what is the purpose of doing it

Comment: Try running a simple artisan command from the crontab maybe showing the version and output that into a file. It will help you further in debugging

Comment: When I do that I receive an error which says `Undefined 400 Not Found`

Comment: `* * * * * cd /home/ddsas9rm2f1g/public_html/clowdlink.com/crm/ && php artisan list > crontab.out 2>&1`
Set your crontab to this and share your output from crontab.out

Comment: OK let me do that

Comment: Response is same as I have mentioned in my question.

Comment: `* * * * * php /home/ddsas9rm2f1g/public_html/clowdlink.com/crm/artisan list > crontab.out 2>&1`
What about this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228726/discussion-between-mohsin-abbas-and-ramesh-nayak).

Answer (score 0):

```
*/30 * * * * php /home/ddsas9rm2f1g/public_html/clowdlink.com/crm/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

**OR**

```
*/30 * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/ddsas9rm2f1g/public_html/clowdlink.com/crm/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

**OR**

```
*/30 * * * * cd /home/ddsas9rm2f1g/public_html/clowdlink.com/crm && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

**Also read full post:** https://devnote.in/how-to-set-auto-database-backup-with-cron-scheduler-in-laravel/